# Specific UNIX Timestamps from DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

So, here's the deal. I've been banging my head off of this for the past couple of hours and really haven't made any headway. I've ready through several of these, and even tried uncle google, but no joy.

I have a project I'm working on that deals with a lot of nightclubs and after-hours locations. As a result, we are redefining the day to be from 5:00am-4:59am. I'm having a heck of a time getting those start/end times from the current time. It must be time-zone specific is the part that is screwing me up.

This is ugly, this is after several different failed theories...I'm really chasing my own tail on this one, so any help would be appreciated.

```
function util_TimeInfo($timezone, $dst){
    // Get current DateTime
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    $dt->setTimezone($tz);

    // split to variables
    $year = $dt->format('Y');
    $month = $dt->format('m');
    $day = $dt->format('d');
    $hour = $dt->format('H');
    $minute = $dt->format('i');
    $second = $dt->format('s');

    // Convert hour to string
    $inthour = intval($hr);

    // Check which day it is a part of
    $mytime[0] = time();
    if($inthour < 5){
        $start_d = date('d', strtotime('-1 day', $mytime[0]));
        $start_m = date('m', strtotime('-1 day', $mytime[0]));
        $start_y = date('Y', strtotime('-1 day', $mytime[0]));
        $end_d = date('d', $mytime[0]);
        $end_m = date('m', $mytime[0]);
        $end_y = date('Y', $mytime[0]);
    } else{
        $start_d = date('d', $mytime[0]);
        $start_m = date('m', $mytime[0]);
        $start_y = date('Y', $mytime[0]);
        $end_d = date('d', strtotime('+1 day', $mytime[0]));
        $end_m = date('m', strtotime('+1 day', $mytime[0]));
        $end_y = date('Y', strtotime('+1 day', $mytime[0]));
    }

    // Create current start of day and end of day in unix timestamp
    $mytime[1] = mktime('05', '00', '00', $start_m, $start_d, $start_y, $dst);
    $mytime[2] = mktime('04', '59', '59', $end_m, $end_d, $end_y, $dst);

    //Return times
    return $mytime;
}
```

Comment: So, using Glavic's comment as a base, I was able to add a if statement to get it working how I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple code:

```php
$tz = new DateTimezone('Europe/Berlin');
$now = new DateTime('now', $tz);
$start = new DateTime('today 5:00am', $tz);
$end = new DateTime('tomorrow 4:59am', $tz);
if ($now < $start) {
    $start = new DateTime('yesterday 5:00am', $tz);
    $end = new DateTime('today 4:59am', $tz);
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/107877)</kbd>

Comment: Almost, it gets messed up in that murky area between midnight and 5am. I fixed it with an if statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Glavic's code as a base, I was able to get it working how I wanted with an if statement to handle the time between midnight and 5am.

```
// Get current DateTime
$dt = new DateTime();
$tz = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
$dt->setTimezone($tz);

// Set cutoff for 5am
$cutoff = new DateTime('today 5:00am', $tz);

// Adjust start/end for day
if($dt < $cutoff){
    $start = new DateTime('yesterday 5:00:00am', $tz);
    $end = new DateTime('today 4:59:59am', $tz);
} else{
    $start = new DateTime('today 5:00:00am', $tz);
    $end = new DateTime('tomorrow 4:59:59am', $tz);
}
```

Comment: You should also create DateTime object `$dt` with your timezone. See my updated answer.